# R (dplyr package) - At least one row per group (random sampling with 10% rows from each group)

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I'm trying to perform a random sampling from a total of 6173 articles, which are distributed across 80 scientific journals.

It would be interesting if all Journals are included in analyses, however, the number of articles per Journal varies greatly and a pure random process would likely not include them all. Therefore, it was suggested that including 10% of articles per Journal would be a good fit.

To achieve this, I used the code below. However, due to non-integer numbers, Journals with one article each were ignored since the output was lower than 0.5 and rounded to zero.

To maintain the sample with as fewer articles as possible, I would like to apply the ceiling function only to count values between 0 and 1, the remaining values are better of with the standard round function.

This problem can be partially solved by manually searching the absent articles and corresponding Journals, but this does not contribute to any learning skills and it is really not a good solution either.

I would really appreciate any suggestions considering the code used, although I apologize if this problem might seem too trivial.

```
library(dplyr)
    journal <- dataset %>% dplyr::group_by(Journal) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = 0.1 * n())

sample <- function(journal, frac)
  {
  if(journal < 1)
  {sample_n(journal, ceiling({{frac}} * n()) )}
  else 
  {sample_n(journal, round({{frac}} * n()) )}
}

dataset_randomised <- dataset %>% sample(0.1)

print(dataset_randomised)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simple random sampling from groups with specified sample size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365645/simple-random-sampling-from-groups-with-specified-sample-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select rows which is maximum of 1 or 0.1 * number of rows for the journal.

```
library(dplyr)
journal <- dataset %>% group_by(Journal) %>% sample_n(size = max(1, round(n() * 0.1)))
```

Comment: Hello Ronak! Thank you very much for your attention and prompt reply. The suggested code worked perfectly, all journals are being correctly addressed.